# Hosting Account Free Space

Tags: php

I have a spot on my cms dashboard where I want to echo how much free space I have left to use on my hosting account. What kind of php tags am I going to need for this? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to do this on my old hosting acc

```
$free = disk_free_space("/");
$total = disk_total_space("/");
$percent = ($free/$total)*100;
```

Comment: So since that function returns the number in bytes I divide that by 1048576?

Comment: Yes, to get the figure in megabytes.

Comment: What do you suggest I do then Mobinga?

Answer (score 3):

The function is [disk_free_space](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php), however, on shared web hostings it's often disabled for security reasons.