# Check the free space for a user on web hosting

Tags: php, hosting

I want to check the free space left on my server (using hosting service). However, I don't want to know the size of a whole disc, that my account accidentally is on. I only want to know, that I have used 456 MB from 1 GB of bought space.

I have tried to use code from this answer ([Hosting Account Free Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366198/hosting-account-free-space)), let me cite it:

```
$free = disk_free_space("/");
$total = disk_total_space("/");
$percent = ($free/$total) * 100;
echo $percent;
```

There is a problem, however. At first it give me a whole free space on the real device. I have 1GB space on my hosting, and this solution tells me that I have 202 GB free. 
BTW, I don't really understand why this question was closed. Maybe it was not clear, but the problem exists and the accepted answer is a little wrong in my opinion.

I have in mind a solution that is using `exec()` and bash function, but the question is: **Is this possible using only PHP, without using `exec()`?** *`exec()` is sometimes blocked, and should be avoided due to code verification problems*. Of course, for example `mysqldump()` should be run using `exec()`, but this is one of few exceptions.

**Possible idea:** I though about summing up all the files that are on my server, and in some kind of config.php file enter the account space manually. This one solve the problem, but not in the "nice" way. Especially if someone buys 1 GB more, and forget about the config "constant".

Comment: I doubt there is any information in the system running your hosted stuff which really knows about your limit. Such a limit is typically only enforced on a meta level, either in the virtualization level or even in accounting. Therefore there is no means to really ask the system about your available space. You could count and sum your file sizes but that will not be accurate. The most promising approach would be to use the `du` cli utility, but indeed you'd need execute permission which typically is not available in a cheap hosted environment.

Comment: Your hosting space will consists of your applications, emails, databases and so on. I doubt that you will get the space of your databases due to limited access. But to get a rough idea you can run the above code on your home directory. I.e. /home/yourusername

Comment: Thx for the information, it was really useful. I thought that it isn't possible but I needed a confirmation. You should make an answer with your thoughts. If noone has another idea, I will approve it :). Thx once more!

Comment: @Jay, wow. Never thought of checking /home/myname. I thought that it will give the same results, and don't even check it. How stupid I am! I will give it a try, and write if this work :).

Comment: @Jacek I have added this as an answer to help others.

Comment: OK, great, I will wait for a moment, and accept it, if there are no other thoughts. @Jay, same results. 200GB free, which is not possible.

Comment: Try disk_total_space("/home/username/") - disk_free_space("/home/username/") What does this give you?

Comment: @Jay, thx for Your help. I took a look in the php documentation, and the disk_free_space returns the real disk free space of a device. Thx for your time, and if you have a moment, please check Fariz solution. The idea is really good! BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the web hosting is using **cPanel** then you can use the cPanel API to call the **getFreeSpace()** and **getSpaceUsed()** function.

```
function getFreeSpace()
{
    $freeSpace = $this->parseIndex('Disk space available', 'float');
    return ($freeSpace == 0) ? 'Unlimited' : floatval($freeSpace);
}
```

Just my 2 penny

cPanel API: "cPanel URL"

**Update:**

I came across the web and found this php script (extracted from a cms plugin). So this is the script that I have tested on my web hosting:

[image: Disk space script]

```
<?php



// SETTINGS - START

// PUT YOUR CPANEL HOSTING USERNAME HERE:
    $username = "username";

// PUT YOUR CPANEL HOSTING USERNAME HERE:
    $password = "password";

// MODIFY THIS PATH TO REFLECT YOUR DOMAIN, REPLACING "DOMAIN-NAME" AND "YOUR-CPANEL-USERNAME":
    $query ="http://cpanel.yoursite.com:2082/xml-api/cpanel?user=USERNAME&cpanel_xmlapi_module=StatsBar&cpanel_xmlapi_func=stat&display=diskusage";

// SETTINGS - END


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl); 

    $xml = simpleXML_load_string($result);

    $df = $xml->data[0]->_count; // used MB
    $ds = $xml->data[0]->_max; // max MB
    $du = $ds - $df; // free MB
    if ($ds > 0) $perc = number_format(100 * $du / $ds, 2); else $perc = 0;
    $color = '#e87d7d';
    if ($perc > 50) $color = '#e8cf7d';
    if ($perc > 70) $color = '#ace97c';
    echo '<li style="font-weight:bold;padding:5px 15px;border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;background-color:#182227;margin-left:13px;color:#afc5cf;">'
        .'Free disk space'
        .'<div style="border:1px solid #ccc;width:100%;margin:2px 5px 2px 0;padding:1px">'
        .'<div style="width:'.$perc.'%;background-color:'.$color.';height:6px"></div></div>'
        .$du.' of '.$ds.' MB free'.'</li>';

?>
```

Source script: http://get-simple.info/extend/plugin/free-disk-space-cpanel/317/

Comment: Ok, this answer is really helpful! Never thought of API's. Let me wait, maybe there are som other ideas, if not, I will accept it. Even if the hosting is not using cPanel, usually it is using something that has API. Great idea, thx :), +1.

Comment: WOW! Nothing else to be said :). Thx for Your help! :).

Comment: @Jacek I'm just guessing that you must be using a cPanel-based webhosting. Not just cPanel, but the premium cPanel (if you know what I mean). This method works best with curl enabled hosting. Glad to help! - p/s I'm a webhoster :)

Comment: OK, thx for the info :). I know a little about cPanel, but I've got all the evening today to learn it. I appreciate the help very much!